# Wordpress. contact-info and css didnt change

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

THere is theme 
https://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Naturelle
[image]
and at the bottom of the page you see contactinfo(grey color) with email, adress and telephone number, but when you go (NATURE NEWS) in bottom i dont see it, how i can make this footer in all pages?
example: https://silas.kaunas.lm.lt/ 
in all pages are same footer,

second question, when i update css file, nothing happens after i clear cache , or press f5, how i can instantly update it?

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] in the question - read this: [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Because all other page was redirect to other link: https://demo.themeisle.com/naturelle/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the theme, you can usually add the footer from the settings.
You control well.
In case this is not there, you need one `get_footer()` ( see this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/ ) on every page you want a footer.
**ATTENTION**
Do not add directly to your theme's theme code, but use a theme-child ( see https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes ), otherwise you will lose the changes you made to the first update.

Comment: but when i make pages later, i always have to add get_footer() ? so its not good decision., because if you see header is always on top, and when i create new page, i see everytime header, i need same with footer, to see it everytime, 

i want to be same like here: 

https://silas.kaunas.lm.lt/

look at this bottom, there is footer. 
then go to other page on header (example : paslaugos ir klausimai) in all pages there are same footer

Comment: Then this is not part of the footer but it is a section. The advice I can give you and create (or copy) that part of code in the file `page.php` just before `get_footer()`. So making every new page you create has that part of code that you wrote

Comment: its not footer. 
its contact-info area.